# What to do with the meta tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

Our [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag is for questions that belong on [the main site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com) but are also about it.

A Stack Exchange employee suggested in chat that that name, [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta), for the tag is confusing, making it seem like that tag is for questions that belong here on [the meta site](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com).

A few suggestions came up in [the ensuing conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/on-the-meta-tag):

- Status quo.
- Merge the [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag into the existing [internet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) tag: all currently [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta)-tagged questions will be tagged [internet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) instead and the [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag will not be usable (as is: it will be a synonym of [internet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)).
- Rename (technically merge) the [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag so its name (and scope) covers online fora more generally.
- Rename (technically merge) the [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag so its name isn't "meta" but so that its scope remains questions about Judaism.SE.

There hasn't been enough input to choose among these. Please state and upvote/downvote your preference (which may be something not on this list); if your preference is a new tag, please include its name in your answer.

---

*Update:* I've implementd the suggestions in [Monica Cellio's answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/975).

Comment: An historical note: The tag predates the current version of the site, and is from a time when it was also used for truly meta question, the sort that are now here on the meta site (and, indeed, a bunch got moved over here when we got this meta site). However, it was also always for questions of the sort it's now used for: question that *do* belong on the main site but are *also* about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just reviewed the 21 questions currently tagged [meta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta).  Some are about this site; some are about the internet in general, and a couple should possibly be migrated or deleted.

Retag the following [internet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet):

- [How should we respond to objectionable content in a public forum?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13819/how-should-we-respond-to-objectionable-content-in-a-public-forum)
- [Why is it necessary to ask a Rabbi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)
- [Reliable Ask-a-Rabbi Websites](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/reliable-ask-a-rabbi-websites)
- [Does participating in Torah discussion websites fit into the spirit of Torah sheB'al Peh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7925/does-participating-in-torah-discussion-websites-fit-into-the-spirit-of-torah-she)
- [Shehecheyanu on new website](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7132/shehecheyanu-on-new-website)
- [False portrayal on an anonymous Q&A site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/false-portrayal-on-an-anonymous-qa-site)
- [Is it considered stealing to look at mi.yodeya while at work?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/394/is-it-considered-stealing-to-look-at-mi-yodeya-while-at-work)
- [What's a good website for asking questions about Jewish life and learning and getting crowd-sourced answers?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/whats-a-good-website-for-asking-questions-about-jewish-life-and-learning-and-ge)

Even though some of them call out J.SE (or mi.yodeya), the questions seem more general to me, sometimes just using this site as an example (like the stealing question).

Retag the following [stackexchange](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) because they are more focused on this site or family of sites and its specific features, like reputation and badges:

- [By using judaism.stackexchange am I fulfilling the mitzvoh of learning Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13102/by-using-judaism-stackexchange-am-i-fulfilling-the-mitzvoh-of-learning-torah)
- [Are You Obligated to Vote a Question You Answer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12101/are-you-obligated-to-vote-a-question-you-answer)
- [How do you CYLOR after posting on judaism.stackexchange.com?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com)
- [Does "reputation scoring" make "the Torah a crown to magnify yourself with"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9445/does-reputation-scoring-make-the-torah-a-crown-to-magnify-yourself-with)
- [The Fanatic Badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/the-fanatic-badge)
- [answering questions on mi.yodeya on Chol Hamoed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6932/answering-questions-on-mi-yodeya-on-chol-hamoed)
- [Ulterior motives on a Q&A site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/ulterior-motives-on-a-qa-site)
- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6846/can-i-ask-questions-about-the-talmud-and-chumash
- [Is this site for Children?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/is-this-site-for-children)
- [Is Mi Yodeya helpful?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/980/is-mi-yodeya-helpful)
- [Make for yourself a website?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/409/make-for-yourself-a-website)
- [What does "mi yodeya" mean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-does-mi-yodeya-mean)

Remove the meta tag (and don't replace it) from:

- [What is your favorite passuk?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5247/what-is-your-favorite-passuk)

Comment: What about this one? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9869/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, [tag:stackexchange] in my opinion.  (I didn't review all the internet ones; that's a much-larger list.)

Comment: It's questions like this that make me prefer the new tag's being [tag:judaism-stackexchange] rather than plain [tag:stackexchange]. But otherwise your breakup looks pretty good.

Comment: @DoubleAA, some of the questions, like the ones about voting and ulterior motives, apply to all SE sites; if more internet sites had voting systems they might even be candidates for the internet tag.  If we make the tag specific to *this* site, what would you do with those questions?  (And the christianity one?)

Comment: I think they should just be [tag:internet]. They do have to do with the internet, even if not the whole internet (whatever that means).

Comment: @DoubleAA, I could go along with moving them all to "internet" or using "internet" and "stackexchange" per my answer.  So long as we don't make a "judaism-stackexchange", which is too specific.

Comment: **I have implemented the suggestions in this answer.**

Answer (score 2):

I support option 4: to rename the tag [mi-yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya) and leave its scope confined to this site.

Comment: I like the idea, except that `se` is ambiguous. (Especially to a newbie who starts typing `judaism` as a tag and chooses the suggested `judaism-se`.) (No +1 from me.)

Comment: @msh210 How about now?

Comment: @msh210 Maybe [tag:mi-yodeya]? That shouldn't attract accidental tag-gers.

Comment: +one now. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

I think we should rename the tag [stackexchange](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) and have it cover Stack Exchange sites only.

Comment: Including this one? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9869/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, yeah.

Comment: @DoubleAA cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9869/is-a-jew-allowed-to-participate-on-christianity-se#comment13865_9880