# "If I'm Jewish how should I behave on this site?" Where do questions like this belong?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If someone wants to ask a question about how Jewish users should behave **on this site specifically** according to Jewish law, where should they ask the question?

**On meta?**

*For:* It is a question about using the site which may be of importance to most users as most users are Jewish.

*Against:* Meta is not a place to ask about Jewish law so the question may be considered off-topic on meta. Posts on meta should be of the same importance for Jewish and non-Jewish users. Therefore, the question may also be considered too localized for meta.

**On main?**

*For:* It is a question about Jewish law, and this is where questions about Jewish law belong.

*Against:* The question's focus on this site only makes it too localized for the main site.

---

So where is it? On meta, on main or perhaps nowhere? I'm not sure all of the arguments above are valid, but I'm not sure any of them is invalid either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions about how Jewish law applies to individuals when using Mi Yodeya [should be](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/975/2) asked on the main site and tagged with [stackexchange](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange).

Not what you asked but related: Questions about what site policy ought to be should be asked on Meta. Consistent with the Jewish character of this community, these questions and their answers may be informed, in part, by Jewish precedent, in which case it might make sense for them to reference parallel questions on the main site about how Jewish law applies to the type of situation described in the Meta question.